# Include classes before Symfony calls session_start()

Tags: session, symfony1

I have a Symfony project and I need to include some classes before Symfony initiates sessions (since the session contains some serealized objects from outside the project).  Where can I put the code to include them?  I have tried putting it in a filter, but it appears the session is started before filters are run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which seems to work.  I have added the directories to autoload.yml in the config file.  By adding inline php code to the yml, i was able to get they dynamic paths that I needed.  For more details on my solutions you can check out this post: 
[Symfony including extra libraries or classes](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/01/symfony-including-extra-libraries-or-classes/)

If anyone one has a better solutions feel free to post it, but otherwise I will consider this answered.